# un select dentro de un case

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema de al parecer de sintaxis en esta linea:

```
'Linea' = CASE WHEN v.Supervisor='NO APLICA' 
THEN  'Linea'=(SELECT t.Linea FROM @TCuota2 AS t) 
ELSE isnull(c.linea,'-') END
```

esto esta dentro de un select y 'Linea' es una columna, me marca el siguiente error :

Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '='.
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'ELSE'.

agradeceria su apoyo para la solucion a este query.
Gracias.

Comment: No me doy cuenta lo que intentas con `'Linea' = ...`, lo más cercano a una sentencia válida podría ser `CASE WHEN v.Supervisor = 'NO APLICA' THEN  (SELECT TOP 1 t.Linea FROM @TCuota) ELSE isnull(c.linea,'-') END`, Comparte el código completo de la sentencia para entender mejor el problema. Saludos.

Comment: Que es línea? una variable T-SQL (estaría mal definida). Si añades contexto a ese fragmento (y lo vuelves un ejemplo mínimo verificable), te podemos ayudar más fácil

Answer (score 1):

al parecer es por que estas tratando de asignar Linea con un igual,

lo que debes hacer es asignar el resultado de tu CASE con AS

ejemplo:

```
CASE WHEN v.Supervisor='NO APLICA' THEN 
       (SELECT t.Linea FROM @TCuota2 AS t) 
    ELSE 
      isnull(c.linea,'-')
 END AS Linea
```